# C++ integer type: special meaning for certain values

Tags: c++, types

We are warned against magic numbers in code with good reason, but is there a good, expressive and type-safe way to solidify constants which have special meaning?  I can think of two possible ways:

Method 1:

```
typedef int NumberOfThreads;
const NumberOfThreads automaticNumberOfThreads = 0;
```

Method 2:

```
class NumberOfThreads
{
    NumberOfThreads(int n) : value(n) {}
    static NumberOfThreads automatic() { return NumberOfThreads(0); }
    bool isAutomatic() const { return value == automatic(); }
    int value;
};
```

I don't really want a complex type, but I do want my special value to be closely tied to the type.  In method 1 it isn't, and lazy users might just hardcode assignment or comparison to `0`.
Method 2 seems a bit heavy for something that isn't much more than an integer value.

Question could be extended to non-integer types and multiple special values.

Perhaps something is possible with `enum`?

Edit:

I realized I can hide the value from the user by using `extern` in my header file

Comment: I think "type safe" is a problem in your question. I think you're trying to enforce correct usage by using data type enforcement. Enum's and good naming are "good enough".

Comment: @Jay - yes, you said it better than me.  I want to enforce correct usage and preferably hide the magic value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't agree with what you do in method 1. There is no need for NumberOfThreads type. That is a constant actually, "number of threads" and the number is an integer. So this is enough and more readable in my opinion.

```
const int NumberOfThreads = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, most if the time it's good but fellow developers can cheat and avoid using the const int: you might see someone write `if (!numberOfThreads) ...` instead of `if (numberOfThreads == automaticNumberOfThreads) ...`

Comment: @paperjam - "Magic constants" is not about forcing people to write good code, but to **allow** them to write readable code. What you can avoid is `if (numberOfThreads == 42)...`, where you don't know what 42 means.

Answer (score 4):

[Enum](http://enel.ucalgary.ca/People/Norman/enel315_winter1997/enum_types/) is basically just giving numbers names. So that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't think `enum` because there is no safe way to convert from `int` to `enum`.

Comment: Just to be safe I'm going to link this here, if you havent read it: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.19

Answer (score 0):

This sample usage shows correct usage enforced and magic value hidden in a the implementation of a function.

```
int numberOfThreads;
/* ... */
numberOfThreads = automaticNumberOfThreads();
/* ... */
numberOfThreads = 1;
/* ... */
numberOfThreads = 16;
/* ... */
if (numberOfThreads == automaticNumberOfThreads())
{
    /* ... */
```